# Regular expression to replace a part of a config file

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I recently made a shell script to automate the process of loading a file into snmp daemon with all the steps.

In the end I need to edit a conf file on the server, and I realize I need to use regular expressions.

I have made a file named *zfiles.txt* where I have all the content I need to insert into a certain range of lines.

```
snmptt_conf_files = <<END
/etc/snmp/file-1
/etc/snmp/file-2
...
...
/etc/snmp/file-n  
END
```

I need to replace everithing between `snmptt_conf_files = <<END` and `END` with the content of `zfiles.txt`.

**BTW** if anyone can provide some good resources to learn regular expressions, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have removed inappropriate language from your question.  Even though you are frustrated with a problem, please remember this is a public forum.

Comment: @paddy ok , sorry for the profanity

Comment: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is the de facto standard for learning about regular expressions.  Regular expressions are awesome once you take a little time to learn how to use them.  Until you do that, they will remain a brain-melting mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/snmptt_conf_files = <<END/,/END/{     # for a here-doc block:
  /^END$/b          # if at the end skip rest
  /<<END/!d         # if not first line delete and skip rest... else insert file:
  r zfiles.txt
}' input
```

As for the resource, Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey E F Friedl is a solid book.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an awk (gnu) one-liner, hope it helps:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}/END$/&&!f{print;f=1;next}!f{print}/END$/&&f{print r $0;f=0}' RS="\0" zfile.txt RS="\n" file
```

let's test a little bit:

```
kent$  cat file
snmptt_conf_files = <<END
/etc/snmp/file-1
/etc/snmp/file-2
...
...
/etc/snmp/file-n  
END

keep1
keep2
keep3

snmptt_conf_files = <<END
/etc/snmp/file-1
/etc/snmp/file-2
...
...
/etc/snmp/file-n  
END

kent$  cat zfile.txt
replace1
replace2
replace3
```

now execute the one-liner:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}/END$/&&!f{print;f=1;next}!f{print}/END$/&&f{print r $0;f=0}' RS="\0" zfile.txt RS="\n" file
snmptt_conf_files = <<END
replace1
replace2
replace3
END

keep1
keep2
keep3

snmptt_conf_files = <<END
replace1
replace2
replace3
END
```

it seems the one-liner does the job for you. regarding the regex resources, I think if you google it , you will get >10k result. take one you like and learning by doing.